# Arrays merging and Json encoding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I generate an unknown number of arrays like this:

```
for ($t=0;$t<2;$t++) {
  for ($xx=0;$xx<$totf[$t];$xx++) {
    $otdata[$t][$xx] = array("".$otname[$t][$xx]."" =>
        ['games'=> $otg[$t][$xx], 
        'mint'=> $otqmint[$t][$xx], 
        'pct'=>$otpct[$t][$xx]]);
  }
}
```

I need this arrays to be merged before encoding the result to a `.json`file.

I do it like this:

```
$newot= array_merge_recursive($otfdata);
$myJsondata = json_encode($newot);
file_put_contents('json/myJson.json', $myJsondata);
```

The `myJson.json`file that results is something like this:

```
[[{"John":{"games":"1","mint":"3.65","pct":"0"}},
{"Mary":{"games":"1","mint":"0.625","pct":"12"}},
...
{"Whatever":{"games":"1","mint":"0.325","pct":"4"}}]]
```

And I don't know how to manage this file. I mean, I would like to do something like this:

1) In php, I want to reach the "mint" data point of "Mary" => "0.625".

```
$myfile=file_get_contents("json/myJson.json");
$mydata = json_decode($myfile,true);
$myResult=$mydata["Mary"]["mint"];
```

Obviously, this does not work.

2) In jQuery, I want basically the same: to reach the "mint" data point of "Mary".

```
  var gdatafile = "json/myJson.json";
  $.getJSON(gdatafile, function (gjson) {
    var myResult=gjson["Mary"].mint;
    $('#resultContainer').text(myResult);
  });
```

My problems:

A) I think the first problem I have is during the merging of the different arrays. The way I do it generates `[[` at the beginning and at the end, and I think this is incorrect.

B) Apart from that, is it correct the way I do it in jQuery?

What I need:

1) To merge and encode the arrays in a way it looks like this:

```
{"John":{"games":"1","mint":"3.65","pct":"0"},
"Mary":{"games":"1","mint":"0.625","pct":"12"},
...
"Whatever":{"games":"1","mint":"0.325","pct":"4"}}
```

I think this would solve problem A.

2) To confirm wether the way I do it in jQuery is correct or not.

Thanks

Comment: array_merge_recursive — Merge two or more arrays recursively

Comment: array_merge_recursive is what I am using.

Comment: you are having the different names in the array keys that's why you are getting the `nested arrays` i.e, array of arrays http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php check the example

Comment: Sundar I don't understand what you mean. How would you change the way I build the arrays or the way I merge them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the array on a expected format like below

```
<?php

$data = array();

for ($t=0;$t<2;$t++) {
  for ($xx=0;$xx<$totf[$t];$xx++) {

    //create the temporary array
    $temp = array(
        'games'=> $otg[$t][$xx], 
        'mint'=> $otqmint[$t][$xx], 
        'pct'=>$otpct[$t][$xx]]
    );

    //identify the array key
    $key = $otname[$t][$xx];

    //check the key is exist or not
    if(isset($data[$key])) {

        //take the existing value as a backup
        $exone = $data[$key]; 
        //overwrite the array
        $data[$key] = array();

        //check the exsiting array is multidimension or not
        if(isset($exone[0])) {
            foreach ($exone as $one) {
                //push the array to the respective key
                array_push($data[$key], $one);
            }
        }
        else {
            //if single dimension then make it multi dimension
            array_push($data[$key], $exone);            
        }

        //push the latest array to the same key
        array_push($data[$key], $temp);

    }//create the new array for the key
    else {          
        $data[$key] = $temp;
    }

    /*$otdata[$t][$xx] = array("".$otname[$t][$xx]."" =>
        ['games'=> $otg[$t][$xx], 
        'mint'=> $otqmint[$t][$xx], 
        'pct'=>$otpct[$t][$xx]]);
    }
*/}

//print the json data
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Great! Appreciate it.